# Creating temporary table runs for 30 minutes and does not finish

Tags: mysql, join

I am joining 7 tables and trying to create a temporary table for further analysis but my query is not finishing.

Then from the temporary table I am creating another temporary table which would hold distinct values in each column:

```
create TEMPORARY TABLE all_data_counts as (

select date,
count(DISTINCT(gclid1)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid2)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid3)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid4)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid5)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid6)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid7)),
count(DISTINCT(gclid8))


from all_data group by date
);

select * from all_data_counts
```

If I run the full code the query is not finishing after letting it run for 20 minutes.

If I only run the `left join` part and select it to be displayed it takes 30 seconds to join and display it.

Would you have an idea why would it not create and display the temporary table with `count(distinct)` values?

The tables have the following rows:

I do understand that this question does not have a MCRE, this is sort of a question with the logic itself, is there some kind of logic which I do not follow when trying to achieve the following output:

all_data_counts

```
Date         gclid1   gclid2   gclid3   gclid4   gclid5   gclid6   gclid7   gclid8
2019-12-10   1000     900      800      700      600      500      400      300
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

How does your temporary compare with just running the whole thing straight off...

```
select date,
count(DISTINCT(gclid1)) a,
count(DISTINCT(gclid2)) b,
count(DISTINCT(gclid3)) c,
count(DISTINCT(gclid4)) d,
count(DISTINCT(gclid5)) e,
count(DISTINCT(gclid6)) f,
count(DISTINCT(gclid7)) g,
count(DISTINCT(gclid8)) h


from 
( 
select g.date
     , g.gclid gclid1
     , k.click_id_from_request_url gclid2
     , i.gclid gclid3
     , s.Gclid gclid4
     , d.Gclid gclid5
     , ko.Gclid gclid6
     , vo.gclid as gclid7
     , v.gclid as gclid8
  from full_google g
  left 
  join full_cf_click k 
    on k.click_id_from_request_url = g.gclid 
  left 
  join full_cf_session_init i
    on i.gclid = g.gclid 
  left 
  join full_session_start s
    on s.Gclid = g.gclid 
  left 
  join full_clickout_database d
    on d.Gclid = g.gclid 
  left 
  join full_clickout_has_offers ko
    on ko.Gclid = g.gclid 
  left 
  join full_conversions_has_offers vo
    on vo.gclid = g.gclid  
  left 
  join full_conversions_api v
    on v.gclid = g.gclid
) x
group by date;
```

Comment: Hi, it did run for 2 minutes and ended up displaying the information. Do you have a clue why would it have problems with the temporary table?

Comment: I expect that there's wide ranging discussion on the limitations of temporary tables, but it's beyond my pay-grade to speculate.

Comment: Thank you for your help with my question sir, have a nice day.